# How to tell if a "->" operator eventually returns a type?

Tags: c++, templates, operator-keyword

I realize that the whatever is returned by the `operator->` will call its own `operator->` in a function call like this:

```
someVarWithOverloadedOperator->someFunc();
```

And that process of calling `->` functions will continue until one of them is a pointer and then `someFunc` is called from that pointer.

My question is: is there way to force a template argument to have its `->` operator eventually return a certain class:

```
template<typename ThisClassOperatorMustReturn_TypeA_>
class MyClass{
  void foo() {
    ThisClassOperatorMustReturn_TypeA_ var;  
    var->someClassAFunc();  //I need this `->` operator to return type "A"
  }
};
```

Any way to do this?

Comment: Must the certain class be used "as is", or can you add a specific method, or a member to the class, for the purpose of implementing this template restriction?

Comment: You want that it return `A` in the chain call, in the first call, or at the end of the chain (so `A*`) ?

Comment: Have you tried a static assertion of `std::is_same` between `A*` and `declltype(var.operator->())` (after discarding `const` if relevant)?

Comment: @Jarod42 I want the end of the chain to be an `A*`

Comment: @TonyD That will not work because `declltype(var.operator->())` could be an in between type (for example `A*` could be `var.operator->().operator->();`

Comment: @DarthRubik: ahhh - I missed the "eventually" in the question's text, focusing on the misnomer `ThisClassOperatorMustReturn_TypeA_`.  Do you have a function in `A` that returns say `A`, `A&`, `A*` - then you can likely use `decltype` on the function call with some dummy args.  Or you need something more general-purpose / reusable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may create a traits for that:

```
template <typename T>
using arrow_type = decltype(std::declval<T>().operator ->());

template <typename T, typename ArrowType = arrow_type<T>>
struct arrow_last_type
{
    using type = typename arrow_last_type<ArrowType>::type;
};

template <typename T, typename P>
struct arrow_last_type<T, P*>
{
     using type = P*;  
};
```

and then

```
static_assert(std::is_same<A*, arrow_last_type<ClassToTest>::type>::value, "unexpected");
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a2649bf1822e78fc)